# unix: cut with .gz file

Tags: unix, grep, cut

I use 'cut' method to grep through some logs:

```
cut -d'#' -f3-8 logs.txt | grep 'code:1'
```

Does anybody know how to use it with .gz file?

Any of these doesn't work:

```
zcut -d'#' -f3-8 logs.gz | zgrep 'code:1'
zcut -d'#' -f3-8 logs.gz | grep 'code:1'
cut -d'#' -f3-8 logs.gz | zgrep 'code:1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you can use this:

```
$ zcat logs.gz | cut -d'#' -f3-8 | grep 'code:1'
```

The zcat command uncompresses the logs.gz file and writes the uncompressed data on standard output.